# Warning: require_once(/HTML/Template/ITX.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\main\login.php on line 13

Tags: php, wampserver, pear

I've never used PEAR libraries, but now I need to modify the scripts that someone wrote php with PEAR libraries. I installed WAMP server and PEAR packages. The pear is installed in the directory `'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40'`. My website contents is installed in the directory `'C:\wamp64\www\mysite'`. When I typed `'http://localhost/mysite/main/login.php'` on a browser, there is always errors below.

> Warning: require_once(/HTML/Template/ITX.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\main\login.php on line 13
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/HTML/Template/ITX.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\main\login.php on line 13

Line 13 in login.php: `require_once "/HTML/Template/ITX.php";`

`"/HTML/Template/ITX.php"` is installed in the directory `"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\pear"`.
I added `"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40"` in the path of system variables and added `'include_path=".;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\pear"'` in the file of `php.ini`, but the issues still exist.

Can anyone help me solve the issues? Thank you very much.

Comment: is the php.ini effective (display phpinfo() and check the include_path setting)? What happens if you prefix the backslash at the beginning of the require_once line with a dot (".") character?

Comment: This is not specifically related to PEAR, it is about using the include_path ini directive in conjunction with require_once(). You can safely use `/` slashes in path on windows in PHP. I would even say it's recommended. docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: The leading `\\` is causing the search to go to the root folder and start looking there, remove the first `\\` and see it that works